# FB mentions doesn't work while using /{comment-id}/comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating comments to a post on FB page using Graph API `/{comment-id}/comments` edge. Everything works like a charm but when I'm trying to send a comment with mention as stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/mentions/) nothing happens. I'm sending 
`some-irrelevant-text @[valid-user-id]`
and what I get is nothing. To be more exact I get `some-irrelevant-text` but `@[valid-user-id]` is doing exactly nothing. Blank space

I'm using graph api v3.1